# How to Properly Switch Between Views

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm making an iOS app (first actual app that isn't Hello World), and it will have 2 screens. I asked on here before how to make one screen (or View Controller) open another, and this is what I figured out to use:

`[self presentViewController:[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"statView"] animated:YES completion:nil];`

It works. However, it gives me the following message when this runs:

`Unknown class statView in Interface Builder file.`
(Note: this doesn't stop me from using the app, it just seems to be a warning.

This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong. Also, it seems I'm instantiating this new view controller, but never getting rid of it. So when I go back and forth, I imagine I might be leaving these View Controllers instantiated as new every time?

So my question is:

1. If there is a better way to switch between these windows, how can it be done?
2. If this is correct, why the error message?

Comment: 1. I use performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: 2. One of your view controller should have the identifier named stateView (I do that in storyboard). If not, I wonder why it would switch to the second view?

Comment: And I only use performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: when I do a "manual segue" (A manual segue is also something you set in storyboard BTW, but you decide when to transit to it with the code). Otherwise just do it directly in storyboard.

Comment: The normal way to manage multiple screens is with a UINavigationController.

Comment: So I removed my old way of doing it, and just used Storyboard to link the views by just linking a button to the second view. It works, but behaves in the exact same way as before (including the `Unknown class statView in Interface Builder file.` error). Is making a modal segue using Storyboard the same thing as what I was doing before? It's worth noting that I am not using a NavigationController.

Comment: I would use a NavigationController, but does that mean I'll have to basically rewrite everything I have so far to switch over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy way is unsing the Storyboard.
Add a button and link it to the second view.

You can use a Segue to parse data:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SEGUENAME"]) {
        SecondViewController *secondViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        secondViewController.parameter = parameter;    // Parse a value
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what this code does? How should I be calling this? I have a button that currently calls a changeToStatView method which I was using to change to the new view controller. I imagine I would replace that method call with somehow calling this prepareForSegue, but I'm still new to this syntax and I'm unsure what this method requires to be passed to it.

Comment: Make a .m file based on a UIViewController. Connect this file in the Storyboard to a View Controller. In this file you can perform all actions on the VC. I normally include the prepareForSegue at the bottom of the .m file.